# nuget not installing file in project\bin directory

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

Working in VS 2019 .NET framework 4.8
For my C# class library project, I ran nuget spec to create a nuspec file for the dll and its dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyId</id>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <title>MyTitle</title>
    <authors>Me</authors>
    ....
    <dependencies>
      <dependency id="dll1" version="1.0.0" />
      <dependency id="dll2" version="2.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

No problems building the nuget package. In my consuming project (MyProject), I installed that package, and after building MyProject, the class library dll and the dependency files are placed in the MyProject\bin directory. Great.

However I need to get another file into directory MyProject\bin, let's call that file MyFile.txt. I first tried using the  element:

```
  ..... 
      <dependency id="dll2" version="2.0.0" />
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
   <file src="MyFile.txt" target="lib" />
  </files>
</package>
```

No luck. While the file is in the packages\lib folder, it does not get placed in MyProject\bin.

I then removed the  element and tried the  element within the  tag:

```
  .....  
    <contentFiles>
      <files include="MyFile.txt" buildAction="None" copyToOutput="true" flatten="true" />
    </contentFiles>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

No luck that way either. Is there a way to accomplish what I need to do? It looks like it may involve having some folders in my class library root folder, but not sure what folders (content?) or how to properly reference them in the nuspec file. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neglected to update this post with the answer I found.
Using the `<files><file /></files>` logic is what solved it. It involved the use of the target attribute and using the *content* keyword in the value:

```
  <files>
    <file src="content\bin\MyFile.txt" target="content\bin" />
  </files>
```

It's in the documentation, I unfortunately missed that even upon multiple readings. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#dependencies-element